# how to read a file name that icludes spaces

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want the user to choose the file named "main folder"
but if i just use
`read foldername`
`ls $foldername`
it just reads the words "main" and "folder" separately (basically executing `ls main` instead of `ls "main folder"`how can i make so it includes spaces ?
I have tried `read -r foldername` but no luck

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a reproducible snippet showing how you used the `read` command, and how you determined that it reads the words separately

Comment: The culprit is not the `read`, but your usage of the variable `foldername`. Enclose it in double quotes while using it.

Comment: @steeldriver i think i did what you asked , not really sure if i helped

Comment: OK so it's not the `read` that's the problem here - it's the unquoted expansion of the variable afterwards - unless you're using `zsh` it needs to be `ls "$foldername"` to prevent word splitting and glob expansion.

Answer (score 1):

*Did you mean: Print the file out to the command line? If yes:*

Use `cat "filename with spaces.txt"` or `cat filename\ with\ spaces.txt`.